# Booting in insecure mode error

Tags: boot, uefi

I've seen answers to this question before, but I don't quite get what they mean. I don't really know anything about stuff like unsigned drivers, etc. So I was wondering if I should just ignore this message because it's incorrect or if there is really something wrong. I have secure mode enabled in BIOS, but does this message mean that it's actually not?

Error:

```
If you want get rid of the message about Insecure Boot you need to enable secure boot. To do this you need turn on validation in module MOK (Machine Owner Key):

sudo mokutil --enable-validation

You will be asked to enter twice temporary password and than after reboot get a possibility to change validation state.

If validation is enabled than no more message about insecure boot appears. But remember, you will not be able to run any unsigned drivers: nVidia drivers and VirtualBox will not be working.

To disable validation type:

sudo mokutil --disable-validation

and then reboot.

If you disable validation and have in BIOS Secure Boot switched ON, still
you will not be able to boot anything that wasn't signed. Even though
your ubuntu has validation disable but "is seen" by BIOS (UEFI) as signed
because of shim-signed package. Shim package while your ubuntu is booting
checks what is the MOK state and if validation is disabled shows message
"Booting in insecure mode".
```

Thanks!

Comment: Secure boot is a complex security topic and is quite technical. Your question is too broad. Read the secure boot documentation and ask a more specific question. What problem are you having ? See http://www.pcworld.com/article/2951559/operating-systems/how-to-install-linux-on-a-pc-with-secure-boot-enabled.html and http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/take-control-your-pc-uefi-secure-boot and https://wiki.debian.org/SecureBoot

Answer (score 0):

If you disable Secure Boot in BIOS, you will not see this message.

Generally speaking the Secure Boot option does not improve security of the system against any modern threats.

The Secure Boot feature was invented by Microsoft. The main idea was to control OS installations. Nothing about security.

For Linux based systems Secure Boot does not make any sense. Linux has its own security features. If you have enough control over the system to install kernel modules, you have enough permissions to do anything you like. So the Secure Boot does not help.

Comment: I think this answer is both an oversimplification and misleading. Secure boot certainly improves security against modern threats. It does not control OS installed, it merely checks kernel modules. You can sign the modules and boot ubuntu with secure boot enabled which does increase security by preventing loading of insecure or unknown kernel modules and disabling secure boot certainly affects windows and linux. You need to know much more about the OP before making sweeping claims.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen The current implementation of secure boot is extremely oppressive to any OS besides Windows. Microsoft effective controls firmware implementation in all but professional and custom-built PCs. In addition, there are very few security benefits- malicious attackers can simply use a signed kernel as a mask for malware. Even more, newer ARM systems that may ship with secure boot firmware *will not* be allowed to turn this off.

Comment: @PatrickNegus - That is your opinion but I disagree with you. Secure boot is OS agnostic and there are linux / open source solutions so a good chunk of your claim is out dated and to be honest FUD.